# How to change hyperlink in Excel using formulas based on condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to switch to different sheet in the same workbook based on the date user enters.
Condition is if user enters a date before July, the link should point to 'Before July 1' and if the date entered is after July, the link should point to 'After July 1' sheet.
I do not want to use macros just excel formulas.

What I wrote is this:
=IF(MONTH(C5)<7,HYPERLINK('Before 1 July'!B2,"SheetOne"),HYPERLINK('After 1 July'!B2,"SheetTwo"))

It first checks the month entered by user if its less than 7 means before july the link points to 'Before July 1' sheet, and if its not it should point to 'After July 1' sheet. But even if The link text shows SheetTwo it still points to 'Before July 1' sheet.

I have used excel Evaluate formula and its showing correct results! Please help me out how to achieve this or is there any other means I can jump to sheet within same workbook based on user input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
=IF(MONTH(C5)<7,HYPERLINK("#'Before 1 July'!B2","SheetOne"),HYPERLINK("#'After 1 July'!B2","SheetTwo"))

Your hyperlink needs to reference a file; however, if you don't want to do that, you can use the "#" syntax to indicate the current workbook.

Syntax: =HYPERLINK("#'linked sheet name'!linked cell number","your message")

Comment: @Cyber How did you find out about the # syntax? I've never come across this before, and it isn't mentioned in the help entry for HYPERLINK.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

=IF(MONTH(C5)<7,HYPERLINK("[MySpreadsheet.xls]Sheet2!B2","Before 1 July"),HYPERLINK("[MySpreadsheet.xls]Sheet3!B2","After 1 July"))

Comment: After doing this I was getting error Cannot find specified file, but with the answer given above, that uses # symbol instead of file name it worked fine.